# How to interpret the results of random variable transformation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose I have two identically distributed random variables $h\sim Uniform[-d/2,d/2]$ and $g\sim Uniform[-d/2,d/2]$. If I do squaring of these random variables the new random variables be $k$ and $l$ with pdf as $f(k)=\frac{1}{d\sqrt{k}}$ range as $[0,d^2/4]$ and $g(l)=\frac{1}{d\sqrt{l}}$ with same range.
Now if I want PDF of sum of $k$ and $l$,i.e., $$m=k+l$$ I am going to do convolution of both as:
$$\int_{0}^{d^2/4}f(x)g(m-x) dx$$
However, the answer gives complex quantities as obtained on Mathematica software:
$$\frac{2}{a^2}\sin^{-1}(\frac{d}{2\sqrt{m}})$$
which of course is strange because for values $m\leq a^2/4$ the integral is not valid. Though, I can understand that the indeterministic nature of integral is due to undefined values of function $f(k)$ and $g(l)$ at zero.

**Does this mean that the random variable $m$ has no pdf ad I should focus on characteristic function. I remember one time for some other random variable transformation calculation I got an imaginary PDF? Does an Imaginary pdf also confers that the random variable has no PDF?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't perform the convolution the way you have set it up.

To illustrate why, consider the simpler example where $X, Y$ are iid uniform on $[0,1]$, and let $Z = X+Y$.  By your reasoning, you would have
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{x=0}^1 f_X(x) f_Y(z-x) \, dx = \int_{x=0}^1 1 \, dx = 1.$$  This is obviously wrong.  Why?  The problem is that the support of all of the variables are finite.  If you wanted to calculate specifically $f_Z(0.5)$, the above integrand would be $f_X(x) f_Y(0.5 - x)$, which will be zero if $x > 0.5$.  And similarly, $f_Z(1.5)$ doesn't work because now the integrand is zero if $x < 0.5$, despite the fact that $Z = X + Y$ could be as large as $1+1 = 2$.

What is the correct way to perform the convolution in this case?  One approach is to use indicator functions to write the density:
$$f_X(x) = \mathbb 1(0 \le x \le 1).$$  Then
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{x=0}^1 \mathbb 1(0 \le x \le 1) \mathbb 1 (0 \le z-x \le 1) \, dx.$$
The first indicator is already handled by the limits of integration, so we can drop it.  The second indicator is trickier:
$$\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \int_{x=0}^1 \mathbb 1 (0 \le z - x \le 1) \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \mathbb 1 (x \le z \le x+1) \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \mathbb 1 (x \le z) \mathbb 1 (z \le x+1) \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \mathbb 1 (x \le z) \mathbb 1 (x \ge z - 1) \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=\max(0, z-1)}^{\min(1,z)} 1 \, dx.
\end{align}$$
Now we can work with cases:  if $0 \le z < 1$, then $\min(1,z) = z$, and $\max(0, z-1) = 0$, so then
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{x=0}^z 1 \, dx = z, \quad 0 \le z < 1.$$
And if $1 < z \le 2$, then $\min(1,z) = 1$, and $\max(0,z-1) = z-1$, so then
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{x=z-1}^1 1 \, dx = 1 - (z-1) = 2-z, \quad 1 < z \le 2.$$
And when $z = 1$ everything is simple and we just get $f_Z(1) = 1$.  We can collapse this case into the case $0 \le z < 1$ and so the correct convolution is
$$f_Z(z) = \begin{cases} z, & 0 \le z \le 1 \\ 2-z, & 1 < z \le 2. \end{cases}$$

So you must do the same thing with your more complicated situation.  The setup is $$f_M(m) = \int_{x=0}^{d^2/4} f_K(x) f_L(m-x) \, dx = \int_{x=0}^{d^2/4} \frac{1}{d \sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{d \sqrt{m-x}} \color{red}{\mathbb 1 (0 \le m-x \le d^2/4)} \, dx,$$ where as before, we dropped the indicator $\mathbb 1 (0 \le x \le d^2/4)$ from the first density $f_K(x)$ because this is already handled by the limits of integration.

If you evaluate this correctly, you should find that
$$f_M(m) = \frac{1}{d^2} \begin{cases} \pi , & 0 \le m \le d^2/4 \\
\arccos \left( \frac{m - d^2/4}{m^2/(2d^2)} - 1 \right), & d^2/4 < m \le d^2/2. \end{cases}$$

Interestingly, this implies that the conditional distribution of $M$ given $M \le d^2/4$ is uniform.

Comment: Ultimately, I think that last bit is because the cross-section of the support square grows linearly from the origin until you get to the diagonal, and that exactly balances the higher density of small values for the square of a uniformly distributed random variable.